# Spring Boot entities and OneToMany connections: how to get the required information?

Tags: java, database, spring-boot

For a study project I am working on a database with quotes from different sources, categorized by different topics. My problem is: I would like to keep the topics in a seperate table, for further updates in case of need, referred by their ID from the quotes table (having basically an ID, a Text, and an Author fields). Spring Boot generated for the code

```
    @Entity
public class Quote {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Lob
    private String text;
private String author;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Topic> topics;
```

the quotes table (and topics table, too) and a lookup table for topics and quotes generated (the second one empty). Could you please help me to fill the table with relevant data (my source csv file has the topics as strings, so I can work with that in case of need), but I am not sure, how to let the database know, which quote does belong to which topic, and how to get the information later (I guess, returning the related string a in a getter could solve my second question, but I am getting way too much confused).
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is quite unclear to me, but your mapping looks wrong. How many topics can a quote have? How many quotes can a topic have?

Comment: Theoretically we would like to allow to one quote to have more topics related. Like "Software is like beer: it's better, when it's free." It is software now, but with times it can be also Linux, open-source, or even beer. Depends on the users choice.
Edit: or all topics at the same time, The goal is to find a quote related to a topic, and we would like to allow the same quote to appear for more topics.

Comment: OK, so a quote can have many topics. I guess you can have more than 1 quote for a given topic, right? If so, the association is a many-to-many, not a one-to-many. So start by fixing that. Here's the documentation about many-to-many associations: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many